# How can the key / legend be forced on for Gnuplot in Ruby

Tags: ruby, gnuplot, legend

I was under the impression the key was on by default in gnuplot, but I cannot generate one with my Gnuplot implementation (which is ruby gnuplot). Here's what I have:

```
::Gnuplot.open do |gp|
  ::Gnuplot::Plot.new(gp) do |plot|
    plot.terminal "png size 900,300"
    plot.lmargin  "10"
    plot.output   "plot.png"
    plot.ylabel   "Time delay (s)"
    plot.xlabel   "BJD"
    plot.key      "on"

    @seconds_array.each do |time_delay|

      x = time_delay.map { |point| point[0] }
      y = time_delay.map { |point| point[1] }
      z = time_delay.map { |point| point[2] }

      plot.data << ::Gnuplot::DataSet.new([x, y, z]) do |ds|
        ds.with = "errorb"
        ds.notitle
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can see I've just tried to override the default (which should be on anyway) with the command to turn the key on. I'd be quite happy with the default settings regarding placement and format, but I just cannot generate a key. Any help appreciated.

I should add that this code does work otherwise and generate a plot exactly how I want it, minus the key!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the source of the problem. The command:

```
ds.notitle
```

was suppressing the key / legend. Removing that notitle command thus produces the desired legend. Thus the line:

```
plot.key "on"
```

is, as I suspected, superfluous, because it is set to be "on" by default.